# I set a parent to my Authentication Manager in Spring security but it didn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to practice spring security and this is my spring security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ProjectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

  @Autowired
  AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder;

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager global() throws Exception {
    builder
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
        .withUser("admin")
        .password("123")
        .authorities(() -> "ADMIN");
    return builder.build();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .antMatcher("/hello")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(global());
  }
}
```

and this is my custom authentication provider:

```
@Component
public class CustomProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    return BadCredentialsException("error");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I read about how we can create a parent for authentication manager and tried to test it. every time I make a request using Postman I get 403 error. what is wrong with my configuration?
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07U40.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Spring uses `ProviderManager` class as the implementation of `AuthenticationManager` interface and if you see the implementation of the `authenticate` method you figure out that it only uses parent authentication manager if the child result is `null` not `exception` in your case.

```
if (result == null && this.parent != null) {
            // Allow the parent to try.
            try {
                parentResult = this.parent.authenticate(authentication);
                result = parentResult;
            }
  // other stuff
}
```

so change the following code in `CustomProvider` to returns `null`

```
  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    return AuthenticationException("error");
  }
```

also from the image I noticed you are using http basic authentication but you didn't enable it in your configuration.

```
http
    .antMatcher("/hello")
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

Comment: you're welcome, also consider enabling debug log in spring security @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)  if you are still learning it.